# VBA Convert Subs to Functions Used in My Main Sub

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am trying to adjust my code's architecture by changing my subs into functions called in my code. Currently I have a semi-operating code. The problem I am running into is my For Loop has so many subs being called using multiple different variables being sent through it that it will often crash or take a long time to respond. I believe changing my subs into functions might aid in this or at least make it easier for others to read my code. If anyone has any suggestions as to how I can write my subs columnlocation and rowlocation into functions that would be great.

Here is what my code currently looks like in VBA:

```
Global sysrow As Integer, wsName As String, c As Range, dict As Object, sysnum as String

Public Sub Main() 

Dim wb as Workbook, sysnum as String, c as Range, ws as Worksheet, 
dict as Object, spec_min as Integer, spec_max as Integer 

Set wb = ThisWorkbook 
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") 

Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
For Each c in ws.Range("E2:E15").Cells 
   sysnum = c.value 
   sysrow = c.Row 
   syscol = c.Column 
   
   If Not dict.Exists(sysnum) Then 
         dict.Add sysnum, True 
         If Not SheetExists(sysnum) Then 
               wsName = c.EntireRow.Columns("D").value 
               If SheetExists(wsName) Then 
                  wb.Worksheets(wsName).Copy After:=ws 
                  wb.Worksheets(ws.Index + 1).name = sysnum 
               End If 
         Else 
             MsgBox "Sheet " & sysnum & " already exists." 
         End If 
Call columnlocation 
      For Each specmin in Range("A2:Q2")
          If specmin.value = "SPEC min" Then
            spec_min = specmin.Column 
          End If 
      Next specmin 
      For Each specmax In Range("A2:Q2") 
          If specmax.value = "SPEC max" Then
            spec_max = specmax.Column
          End If 
      Next specmax 
Call rowlocation 

Next c 
End Sub
```

---

```
Function SheetExists(SheetName As String)
   If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook 
   On Error Resume Next 
   SheetExists = Not wb.Sheets(SheetName) Is Nothing 
End Function
```

---

```
Sub columnlocation() 
 
Dim coherencelengthcol As Range, tunrangecol As Range, avpowercol As Range, sweeprtcol As Range, kclockcountcol As Range, kclockdepthcol As Range

    coherencelengcol = Application.Match("Coherence Length (mm)", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Q1"), 0) ' Application.Match looks up the position of the value, 0 means its looking for an exact match case-sensitive
    MsgBox "Coherence length column index is " & coherencelengcol
    IsError (coherencelengcol) ' checks to see if expression returns an error

    tunrangecol = Application.Match("Tuning Range (nm)", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Q1"), 0)
    'MsgBox "Tuning range column index is " & tunrangecol
    IsError (tunrangecol)

    averagepowercol = Application.Match("Power (mW)", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Q1"), 0)
    'MsgBox "Power column number index is " & averagepowercol
    IsError (averagepowercol)

    sweeprtecol = Application.Match("Sweep Rate (kHz)", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Q1"), 0)
    'MsgBox "Sweep rate column index is " & sweeprtecol
    IsError (sweeprtecol)

    kclockctcol = Application.Match("K-Clock Count", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Q1"), 0)
    'MsgBox "K-Clock count column index is " & kclockctcol
    IsError (kclockctcol)

    kclockdepthcol = Application.Match("K-Clock set for Imaging Depth in air (mm)", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Q1"), 0)
    'MsgBox "K-Clock depth column index is " & kclockdepthcol
    IsError (kclockdepthcol)    
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub rowlocation() 

Dim coherencelengrow As Integer, tunrangerow As Integer, averagepowerrow As Integer, sweeprterow As Integer, kclockctrow As Integer, kclockdepthrow As Integer, kclockjitter As Integer

    coherencelengrow = Application.Match("Coherence Length (mm)", Worksheets(sysnum).Range("B:B"), 0)
    MsgBox "Coherence length row index is " & coherencelengrow
    IsError (coherencelengrow)

    tunrangerow = Application.Match("Wavelength Tuning Range", Worksheets(sysnum).Range("B:B"), 0)
    'MsgBox "Wavelength tuning range row index is " & tunrangerow
    IsError (tunrangerow)

    averagepowerrow = Application.Match("Average power", Worksheets(sysnum).Range("B:B"), 0)
    'MsgBox "Averge power row index is " & averagepowerrow
    IsError (averagepowerrow)

    sweeprterow = Application.Match("Sweep Rate", Worksheets(sysnum).Range("B:B"), 0)
    'MsgBox "Sweep rate row index is " & sweeprterow
    IsError (sweeprterow)

    kclockdepthrow = Application.Match("Clock Length", Worksheets(sysnum).Range("B:B"), 0)
    'MsgBox "Clock depth row index is " & kclockdepthrow
    IsError (kclockdepthrow)

    kclockjitter = Application.Match("Clock Jitter Map Clock Count", Worksheets(sysnum).Range("B:B"), 0)
    'MsgBox "Jitter map count row index is " & kclockjitter
    IsError (kclockjitter)

    kclockctrow = Application.Match("Sampling Clocks", Worksheets(sysnum).Range("B:B"), 0)
    'MsgBox "Sampling clocks row index is " & kclockctrow
    IsError (kclockctrow)

End Sub
```

Comment: All of those loops would be much faster if replaced with (for example) `col = Application.Match("Coherence Length (mm)", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Q1"), 0)` Test col using `IsError(col)` to make sure you got a hit.

Comment: `For Each clength In Worksheets(wsName).Range("B:B")` here you're looping cell-by-cell over a million cells, and you do that multiple times.  Generally you'd use something like `Cells(Rows.Count, "B").end(xlUp)` to find the last-used cell and stop there...

Comment: @TimWilliams So I could rewrite it as `For Each clength In Worksheets(wsName).Cells(Rows.Count, "B").end(xlUp)` ?

Comment: Have you tried looking that up?  Might want to get in the habit of checking the online docs while you code…

Comment: @TimWilliams I have found it. I am running into an issue with setting my range for the rowlocation values, if I want the entire row can i not just do Range("B:B")? I also am running into the problem that I thought was solved before where once it reaches the last sheet in the loop, it will throw an error rather than recognizing the next cell is empty and stopping.

Comment: B:B is a column not a row.  Why would you scan the whole column instead of the (likely much smaller) part of it which as any content though?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, I am looking to search the entire column B for key words and then from that see which row they are in based on their positioning in the column B. I have updated my code above to include the Application.Match. Maybe it will be clearer what I mean by B:B

Answer (score 1):

Your code could be re-worked to be a lot more efficient - here's an example of the type of approach you could take, by creating a function which maps all row or column labels/headers using a Dictionary object.

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim mapCol As Object, mapRow As Object, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Set mapCol = HeaderMap(ws.Range("A1:Q1"))    'map values in a row
    Debug.Print mapCol("Coherence Length (mm)")
    Debug.Print mapCol("Tuning Range (nm)")
    
    Set mapRow = HeaderMap(ws.Range("B2:B" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)) 'map values in a column
    Debug.Print mapRow("Wavelength Tuning Range")
    Debug.Print mapRow("Average power")
    
End Sub



'return a Scripting Dictionary keyed on values in `rng`
'  dictionary values are columnn/row numbers, depending on orientation of `rng`
Function HeaderMap(rng As Range) As Object
    Dim dict As Object, c As Range, isRow As Boolean, v
    isRow = rng.Columns.Count > 1 'is rng a row, or a column?
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dict.comparemode = vbTextCompare 'case-insensitive
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 Then dict(v) = IIf(isRow, c.Column, c.Row)
    Next c
    Set HeaderMap = dict 'return the Dictionary
End Function
```

Comment: I am not sure I can just map the rows and columns as I will need to be able to refer to them. I later want to transfer data into a specific cell using row and column indexes to locate the cell's position.

Comment: That's the whole point of this approach - get a "map" which converts a column header or row value to a column or row position.  You do that *once* per range of interest, so you don't have to keep looping over those same ranges over and over.

Comment: I see, so I could replace my sub columnlocation with mapCol and the rowlocation sub with mapRow and then that function will loop through each heading for every c in my range?

Comment: Yes that's about it.

Comment: I am currently updating now. Where should I place the sub tester code in my main code? I am trying it right before I called sub columnlocation but I didnt know if you had a better suggestion for me?

Comment: The code I posted is just an *example* of the type of approach you could take to improve  you code - it's not a copy/paste replacement.

Comment: `If Len(v) > 0 Then dict(v) = IIF(isRow, c.Column, c.Row)` if there's a value in the cel lthen store that value as a key in the dictionary, associated with either the row or column number, depending on what type of range was provided to `rng` (a single row or a single column of cells)

Comment: Ok, and using maps is the best approach to prevent my code from crashing? As you can tell I am not advanced in VBA, so this map function is a bit confusing for me.

Comment: "crashing" can be many things, so this will not protect you in all cases.  It maily helps to speed things up.

Comment: I guess I am looking to reduce the amount of time it takes for the script to run. By creating functions and reducing the amount of if then statements or for loops, wouldnt that speed up the code.

Comment: Creating functions *in itself* doesn't speed up code - it's a way to organize your code into blocks that make sense and to abstract common pieces of login into a single place.  Reducing the amount of cell-by-cell looping and using (eg) Find or Match should give you speed improvement though.

Comment: Ok, so using the Application.Match is the best approach for this situation?

Comment: Yes Match() should work if you only expect a single match in the range.  Your lines (eg) `IsError (kclockdepthrow)` don't do anything though - if that evaluates to True you need to flag up the problem.

Comment: Oh so the lines `IsError (kclockdepthrow)` are not helpful

Comment: I already posted an alternative approach using a Dictionary, in one of your previous questions.

Comment: I do use dictionary in my code. That is how I store all the values from the beginning