# Expected Array Error When No Array Is Present

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have these two functions that are checking for a column index for the specific header assigned to each. For the first function, `sys_position` there is no problem and the message box appears, however in the second function `partnum_position` the expected array error is thrown. The only difference that I can see of the two is the specific header that is assigned in `Set sys_Rng = sht.Cells.Find("System Number"). Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

```
Public Sub Main()
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, system_position As Integer, partnum_position As Integer

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

 system_position = sys_position(ws)
 partnum_position = partnum_position(ws)

 End Sub
```

---

```
 Function sys_position(sys_Rng As Variant) As Integer 
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'define start sheet
Set sys_Rng = sht.Cells.Find("System Number(s)") 'set values to look for

    If Not sys_Rng Is Nothing Then 'if found then do this oporation
       MsgBox ("System Number Column is " & sys_Rng.Column)
    Else
       MsgBox ("No Header Found.")
    End If
Set sys_Rng = Nothing ' clear variable
Set sht = Nothing ' clear variable
End Function
```

---

```
Function partnum_position(partnum_Rng As Variant) As Integer 
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'define start sheet
Set partnum_Rng = sht.Cells.Find("Part Number")

    If Not partnum_Rng Is Nothing Then
       MsgBox ("Part Number Column is " & partnum_Rng.Column)
    Else
       MsgBox ("No " & partnum_Rng & " Header Found.")
    End If
Set partnum_Rng = Nothing ' clear variable
Set sht = Nothing ' clear variable
End Function
```

EDIT

```
 Public Sub Main()
 Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, i As Range, dict As Object, system_position As Long, partnum_position As Long
Dim wbSrc As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Call position 
 End Sub
```

---

```
 Sub position() 

 Dim sht As Worksheet
 Dim sys_Rng As Range, partnum_Rng As Range, syswaivernum As Range, partnumber As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'define start sheet
Set sys_Rng = sht.Cells.Find("System Waiver Number(s)") 'set values to look for
Set partnum_Rng = sht.Cells.Find("Axsun Part Number")

If Not sys_Rng Is Nothing Then 'if found then do this oporation
    MsgBox ("System Waiver Number Column is " & sys_Rng.Column)
Else
    MsgBox ("No Header Found.")
End If

If Not partnum_Rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("Axsun Part Number Column is " & partnum_Rng.Column)
Else
    MsgBox ("No " & partnum_Rng & " Header Found.")
End If

Set sys_Rng = Nothing ' clear variable
Set partnum_Rng = Nothing ' clear variable
Set sht = Nothing ' clear variable
 End Sub
```

Comment: When using `Find`, *always* specify the `What`, `LookAt`, and `LookIn` parameters. See the remarks in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find).

Comment: You are passing worksheet instead of range to the function and then trying to set it?

Comment: @BigBen how do a specific a string value in cells?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes, I want the function to run through the worksheet. Do you mean I need to define the range outside of the function? So move `Set sys_Rng = sht.Cells.Find("System Number(s)")` to be before I call the function ` system_position = sys_position(ws)`

Comment: Posted an answer. See if that is what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** When working with rows, it is advisable to define them as `Long` rather than `Integer`. Excel 2007+ has `1048576` rows so we should always declare the variable which will hold the row value as `Long` instead of `Integer`. You will get an `Overflow` error if you try to store say `1048576` to an `Integer` variable.

**2.** When using `.Find`, use all the necessary parameters.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

Public Sub Main()
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    sys_position
    partnum_position
End Sub
 
Private Sub sys_position()
    Dim aCell As Range
    Set aCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="System Waiver Number(s)", _
        After:=ws.Range("A1"), _
        Lookat:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        MatchCase:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("System Waiver Number Column is " & aCell.Column)
    Else
        MsgBox ("No Header Found.")
    End If
End Sub 

Private Sub partnum_position()
    Dim aCell As Range
    Set aCell = ws.Cells.Find("Axsun Part Number", _
        After:=ws.Range("A1"), _
        Lookat:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        MatchCase:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Axsun Part Number Column is " & aCell.Column)
    Else
        MsgBox ("No Header Found.")
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

**3.**

Considering that you are not returning any value, it is better to use a `Sub procedure` and not `Function procedure`. Your code can be drastically reduced to

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Main()
    FindPosition "System Waiver Number(s)", "System Waiver Number Column is "
    FindPosition "Axsun Part Number", "Axsun Part Number Column is "
End Sub
 
Private Sub FindPosition(SearchText As String, msg As String)
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim aCell As Range
    
    Set aCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:=SearchText, _
        After:=ws.Range("A1"), _
        Lookat:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        MatchCase:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox (msg & aCell.Column)
    Else
        MsgBox ("No " & SearchText & " Header Found.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I get an error saying object required at `Set Cell = ws.Cells.Find("Axsun Part Number", _
        After:=ws.Range("A1"), _
        Lookat:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        MatchCase:=False)`

Comment: I just edited the post. You may have to refresh the page to see the edit. Also you are not using the exact code.. I had typed `Set aCell =` and not `Set Cell =`

Comment: I changed it to `Dim Cell As Range` does the `a` effect the script?

Comment: It did not work, I not get an error saying Expected sub, function, or property

Comment: No but I do not know what other changes you have made. The best thing is to first try the code which is being suggested to you and then once you understand it, make your changes :)

Comment: I tried it how you suggested it and i got the same error as before

Comment: The old code and the drastically reduced code (see new edit) are both tried and tested and it works just fine for me.. Please update the question with the code that you are trying

Comment: I see your new edits, is there a way to write the code as a function rather than make multiple subs, the idea of breaking down the two positions into functions was to reduce the length of my code as they were already in subs before

Comment: `is there a way to write the code as a function rather than make multiple subs, the idea of breaking down the two positions into functions was to reduce the length of my code as they were already in subs before` But I do not have multile subs. Your original code has it. My 2nd code is much much shorter than yours....

Comment: Ok so the best way is to write it as subs and not functions in this case?

Comment: Can you add comments explaining what this means: `Set aCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:=SearchText, _
        After:=ws.Range("A1"), _
        Lookat:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        MatchCase:=False)`

Comment: `Can you add comments explaining what this means:` See the link that @BigBen gave in the comment below your question

Comment: BTW did you try the 2nd code that i gave above?

Comment: I am adjusting my code to show you what I have to see if it works

Comment: ok. Also if you want to understand what are Sub Procedures and Function Procedures are then see the video [What are Sub Procedures and Function Procedures](https://youtu.be/naKfjXbFfJA)

Comment: Ummm, Isn't my 2nd code (which is much shorter) doing the same thing? Also you are still not using the other parameters of `.Find` as suggested by 2 peopl now. Also you are just repeating the .Find code. I used 1 common procedure to do the `.Find`. Anyways, it is your code....

Comment: @SiddharthRout - FYI previously...  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73912301/478884